# How does extern work in namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-variables, constants, extern

I'm running a simple program similar to what I found [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/). It's meant to reduce code bloat when including constants in multiple files. It does this by using const global variables within a namespace with their respective `extern` forward declarations.

**globals.h**

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H_
#define GLOBALS_H_

namespace Constants
{
    // forward declarations only
    extern const double pi;
    extern const double avogadro;
    extern const double my_gravity;
}

#endif
```

**globals.cpp**

```
namespace Constants
{
    // actual global variables
    extern const double pi(3.14159);
    extern const double avogadro(6.0221413e23);
    extern const double my_gravity(9.2); // m/s^2 -- gravity is light on this planet
}
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#include "globals.h"

int main()
{
    double value_of_pi = Constants::pi;

    std::cout << value_of_pi;

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I assume that Constants::pi gets the value pi contained in the globals.cpp Constants namespace, and is able to do so because it has access to the namespace itself from the included globals.h. What I don't understand is why the ***const global definitions/initializations*** in globals.cpp need the `extern` keyword? I tried removing the `extern` keywords in globals.cpp thinking that it wasn't needed, but my program won't run without them. I thought `extern` was only used for forward declarations? Why are they needed for the ***const global definitions/initializations***? Has it something to do with the namespace they are defined in?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> It's meant to reduce code bloat when including constants in multiple files

I would suggest not to focus on this kind of optimizations unless it becomes really necessary, and rather choose the simplest design: define those constants directly in the header file and include that header file from all translation units (".cpp files") that need to access those constants. Since those objects are `const`, they will have internal linkage and the linker won't be screaming at you due to violations of the One Definition Rule.

> I tried removing the extern keywords in globals.cpp thinking that it wasn't needed, but my program won't run without them

That's because namespace-scope `const` objects with static storage duration (like your `pi` variable) have *internal linkage* unless you explicitly define them as `extern`.

> I thought extern was only used for forward declarations?

`extern` is used to declare a variable that is defined in another translation unit (".cpp file"). If the object is `const`, the translation unit that defines it needs to explicitly mark it as `extern` in order for it to have external linkage and be visible from other translation units (this wouldn't be necessary if the object were not `const`).

> Has it something to do with the namespace they are defined in?

No, this is the rule for all namespace-level `const` objects with static storage duration, and it is specified in paragraph [basic.link]/3 of the C++ Standard:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> (3.1) [...] — a variable, function or function template that is explicitly
>   declared static; or,
>
> (3.2) — **a variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage**; or
>
> (3.3) — a data member of an anonymous union.

Comment: I feel semi-compelled to downvote because you haven't pointed out how utterly stupid his scenario is, and instead only focused on the language lawyering which will be of limited value to the questioner.

Comment: @Puppy: feel free to downvote. Your point is valid. Keep in mind, though, that those are not "mutable variables", as you wrote in a comment to the question. They are `const` object. But fair enough, I will edit.

Comment: These aren't, but other examples on the page he took the code from are.

Comment: Ladies, I probably will only use global variables once or twice in my life. I'm only here to understand the language, so if I come across poorly written code I'll know what it means. @AndyProwl Thank you for your detailed explanation. I understand most of it now except for two things. From the website I pulled this off of, it says the variables inside the `namespace Constants` are *actual global variables*, but I thought namespace has scope and therefore anything inside cannot have global scope? And does `Constants::pi` grab the *identifier* from the forward declaration of pi in *globals.h*?

Comment: @WanderingFool: They are namespace-level and they're commonly called "global" because they are not in block scope, but that isn't completely accurate either, since they are not part of the global namespace. They have static storage duration, are created before `main()` is entered and destroyed after it is left, but they do live in the `Constants` namespace and in order to access their name you have to specify `Constants::` (or make that happen implicitly through a using directive or a using declaration). I guess the answer to the last question is "yes": the name is visible thanks to the header